# Subquery returned more than 1 value. when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I run the following query:

to search a particular pattern from the tables

But getting error:

"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression "

```
 DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
 SET @SearchStr = '' 

--drop table #Results

CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
 SET  @TableName = ''
  SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

 WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN

SET @ColumnName = ''
SET @TableName = 'RAP1'

WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName =
    (

        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE         
         TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
            AND    DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')

    )

    IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Results
        EXEC
        (
            'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
            ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
        )
    END
END   
 END
 SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results

 DROP TABLE #Results
```

What is wrong? how to get result? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because table `RAP1` has more than 1 columns, and you're trying to save the values (names) of every column of that table in a single variable (in `SET @ColumnName`).

If the following query returns more than 1 row then that is your problem:

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256)
SET @TableName = 'RAP1'

SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
    AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
```

I would change your script to look something like this:

```
DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchStr = '' 

--drop table #Results

CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110), @PrevColumnName nvarchar(128)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

SET @ColumnName = ''
SET @PrevColumnName = ''
SET @TableName = 'RAP1'

IF @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    WHILE (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN

        SELECT TOP 1 @ColumnName = COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
            AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'decimal')
            AND COLUMN_NAME > COALESCE(@PrevColumnName, @ColumnName)

        IF @ColumnName = @PrevColumnName
            begin
                SET @ColumnName = NULL
                SET @TableName = NULL
            end

        SET @PrevColumnName = @ColumnName

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
        END   
    END
END
SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
```

Comment: Thanks. However, its not returning all the columns that has a particular string I'm searching for (in my @SearchStr )

Comment: @TryingBest Well, I only solved the part of your script where you were having problems running the script. For this issue you're mentioning here I think you need `%` signs for your `LIKE`.

Comment: I have % sign for my like. here: SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + SearchStr + '%','''')   Am I still doing something wrong?